# Why do I get wrong NDVI, EVI values in crop monitoring?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, ndvi, sentinel-2, evi

I have been monitoring agriculture lands with Sentinel-2 S2MSI2A data. I'm calculating NDVI and EVI for the vegetation. The NDVI values are slowly increasing because the growing crops which is look correct, but after hitting around 0.6 NDVI values suddenly the following values about 0.2-0.3.
In the TCI imgages we can see the green areas clearly, and it's comfirmed with fieldwork.
The EVI is much more sensitive, because there are greater values then the -1;1 range while the NDVI values are low like 0.2-0.3.

The monitoring period started from 2021 september and it's still in progress. The wrong NDVI values are started in February, and the EVI values are much higher then I estimated since any crops could be there. For example I've got 0.32 NDVI and 0.67 EVI values in the same time.

Also I'm using ArcMap 10.4.1
[image: NDVI]
[image: EVI]

Comment: Add a few screenshots for better clarification. What is TCI? is it True Color Image composite?

Comment: I added NDVI and EVI images in three different time, and yes TCI is True Color Image composite with blue, green and red bands.